# ADFS Claims Rules

Tags: adfs

I am trying to understand the difference between the following sets of ADFS claim rules in my environment. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Issuance Authorization Rules: The following rules are under this rule set:

**1)** `BlockMicrosoft.Exchange.RPC`

**2)** `Microsoft.Exchange.OfflineAddressBook`

**3)** `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices`

**4)** `Block Microsoft SMTP`

**5)** `Block Microsoft Pop Imap`

**6)** `Block Microsoft Mapi`

**7)** `Block Microsoft NSPI`

**Question:**

a)  Based on my understanding, these rules are blocking the Outlook client from being accessed from the external network, is that accurate?

b)  In addition to blocking the Outlook client, are these rules blocking any other service and/or defining anything else e.g. access to OWA, SharePoint, OneDrive, Outlook etc. via multifactor authentication?

c)  How do I configure ADFS claim rules to enforce MFA for OWA, SharePoint, etc. if not already done by the above rules?

Thank you in advance for your time. 
Ash

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at scenario #5 which explains how to target MFA for browser access @ https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ramical/2014/01/30/under-the-hood-tour-on-multi-factor-authentication-in-adfs-part-1-policy/